# How to cache hibernate collection?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, hibernate-mapping, ehcache

I have two entities **com.gn.entities.Report** and **com.gn.entities.ReportSummary**.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD z.0//EN"  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.gn.entities.Report" table="REPORT" >
     <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
             <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
     <property name="name">
           <column name="NAME" />
     </property>
     <set name="reportSummaryList" table="REPORT_SUMMARY" cascade="all" inverse="true" fetch="join" >
         <key column="RPT_ID" not-null="true"></key>
         <one-to-many class="com.gn.entities.ReportSummary"/>
     </set>
 </class>
```

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN""http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.gn.entities.ReportSummary" table="REPORT_SUMMARY" >
    <composite-id name="id" class="com.gn.entities.ReportSummaryId">
         <key-property name="id" column="ID"></key-property>
         <key-many-to-one name="report" class="com.gn.entities.Report" column="RPT_ID"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="name">
         <column name="NAME" />
    </property>
</class>
```

> I would like to know what is difference between

scenario 1: **cache tag on entity and set**
`<class name="com.gn.entities.Report" table="REPORT" >
<cache usage="read-write" region="report"/>` 
and
`<set name="reportSummaryList" table="REPORT_SUMMARY" cascade="all" inverse="true" fetch="join" >
      <cache usage="read-write" region="report"/>`

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
  <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.gn.entities.Report" table="REPORT" >
    <cache usage="read-write" region="report"/>
     <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
             <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
     <property name="name">
           <column name="NAME" />
     </property>
     <set name="reportSummaryList" table="REPORT_SUMMARY" cascade="all" inverse="true" fetch="join" >
         <cache usage="read-write" region="report"/>
         <key column="RPT_ID" not-null="true"></key>
         <one-to-many class="com.gn.entities.ReportSummary"/>
     </set>
 </class>
```

and

scenario 2: **cache tag on only entity** (`<cache usage="read-write" region="report"/>`)

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.gn.entities.Report" table="REPORT" >
    <cache usage="read-write" region="report"/>
     <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
             <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
     <property name="name">
           <column name="NAME" />
     </property>
     <set name="reportSummaryList" table="REPORT_SUMMARY" cascade="all" inverse="true" fetch="join" >


   <!-- <cache usage="read-write" region="report"/>  -->

         <key column="RPT_ID" not-null="true"></key>
         <one-to-many class="com.gn.entities.ReportSummary"/>
     </set>
 </class>
```

> **Question 1:** In both scenarios Report and ReportSummary will be cached or not ? if yes then what is the use of making entity and collection cache-able?
>
> **Question 2:** Also, does fetching impact caching ( fetch=join or fetch=select )? in both scenarios ?

```
     <set name="reportSummaryList" table="REPORT_SUMMARY" cascade="all" inverse="true" fetch="join" >

     and
     <set name="reportSummaryList" table="REPORT_SUMMARY" cascade="all" inverse="true" fetch="select" >
```

**Update :-**

Ok, which means I have to make **ReportSummary** also cacheable. 
After doing that I found that I am still getting log messages as below:-

17:23:04,824 TRACE DefaultLoadEventListener:403 - **Attempting to resolve: [com.gn.entities.ReportSummary#component[id,report]{report=com.gn.entities.Report#1, id=1}]**

**17:23:04,824 TRACE DefaultLoadEventListener:427 - Object not resolved in any cache: [com.gn.entities.ReportSummary#component[id,report]
{report=com.gn.entities.Report#1, id=1}]**

17:23:04,824 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:3923 - Fetching entity: [com.gn.entities.ReportSummary#component[id,report]{report=com.gn.entities.Report#1, id=1}]
17:23:04,824 DEBUG Loader:2105 - Loading entity: [com.gn.entities.ReportSummary#component[id,report]{report=com.gn.entities.Report#1, id=1}]
17:23:04,824 DEBUG SQL:104 - 
    /* load com.gn.entities.ReportSummary */ select
        reportsumm0_.ID as ID1_1_0_,
        reportsumm0_.RPT_ID as RPT2_1_0_,
        reportsumm0_.NAME as NAME3_1_0_ 
    from
        REPORT_SUMMARY reportsumm0_ 
    where
        reportsumm0_.ID=? 
        and reportsumm0_.RPT_ID=?
Hibernate: 
    /* load com.gn.entities.ReportSummary */ select
        reportsumm0_.ID as ID1_1_0_,
        reportsumm0_.RPT_ID as RPT2_1_0_,
        reportsumm0_.NAME as NAME3_1_0_ 
    from
        REPORT_SUMMARY reportsumm0_ 
    where
        reportsumm0_.ID=? 
        and reportsumm0_.RPT_ID=?

17:23:04,824 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:319 - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@e3c0e40: /* load com.gn.entities.ReportSummary */ select reportsumm0_.ID as ID1_1_0_, reportsumm0_.RPT_ID as RPT2_1_0_, reportsumm0_.NAME as NAME3_1_0_ from REPORT_SUMMARY reportsumm0_ where reportsumm0_.ID=** NOT SPECIFIED ** and reportsumm0_.RPT_ID=** NOT SPECIFIED **]
17:23:04,824 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl:329 - Registering last query statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@e3c0e40: /* load com.gn.entities.ReportSummary */ select reportsumm0_.ID as ID1_1_0_, reportsumm0_.RPT_ID as RPT2_1_0_, reportsumm0_.NAME as NAME3_1_0_ from REPORT_SUMMARY reportsumm0_ where reportsumm0_.ID=** NOT SPECIFIED ** and reportsumm0_.RPT_ID=** NOT SPECIFIED **]

> Which means that hibernate found the ReportSummary id and it will hit
>   database to get the ReportSummary entity using that id ?

**So , If there are 10000 ReportSummary entities there will be 10000 database hits ?**

Answer (score 0):

`ReportSummary` instances are not cached in either case, because you did not mark that entity class to be cacheable.

If `Report` entity is declared to be cacheable, then obviously Hibernate will cache its instances in the second-level cache.

If `reportSummaryList` is not cacheable, then that collection will not be cached, regardless of whether `Report` is cacheable or not.

If `reportSummaryList` is cacheable, then Hibernate caches ids of `ReportSummary` instances present in the `reportSummaryList`. It does not matter whether `ReportSummary` is cacheable or not; ids are cached in a separate cache entry. However, in this case you may want to make `ReportSummary` entity cacheable as well, to improve performance when reading its instances based on ids contained in the cached collection entry.

More details [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-collection-cache-work/) and [here](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache).

Comment: thanks for quick reply , I have updated my question . could you please comment on that.

Comment: Take a look at fetch plans and fetch strategies to optimize loading. Regarding caching, if an entity instance is in the cache, then it will not be loaded from the database. The first time it obviously has to be loaded. Also, check the links I provided and other documentation about L2 cache to be able to decide whether an entity is a good candidate for caching or not.